# Automatically Compress and Send Updated Folders to Telegram Using Node.js

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

I have the following code, and I can't find where the bug is. I hope you can help me fix the code. This is my first time posting on Stack Overflow, so there may be some mistakes. I apologize if any occur.

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const chokidar = require('chokidar');
const fs = require('fs');
const archiver = require('archiver');
const moment = require('moment');

// Configuration Information
const telegramBotToken = 'YOUR_TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN';
const chatId = 'YOUR_CHAT_ID'; // ID of the channel or group you want to send to
const baseFolder = 'path_to_your_folder'; // The folder you want to monitor

const bot = new TelegramBot(telegramBotToken, { polling: true });

let isProcessing = false; // Variable to track if processing is currently in progress

const sendMessage = (message) => {
  bot.sendMessage(chatId, message);
};

const createZipArchive = async () => {
  if (isProcessing) {
    return; // Another processing is already in progress
  }

  isProcessing = true; // Start the processing
  const timestamp = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
  const zipFileName = `backup_${timestamp}.zip`;

  const output = fs.createWriteStream(zipFileName);
  const archive = archiver('zip', { zlib: { level: 9 } });

  output.on('close', () => {
    sendMessage(` Folder backup created at: ${timestamp}`);
    bot.sendDocument(chatId, zipFileName);
    fs.unlink(zipFileName, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(`Error deleting ZIP file: ${err}`);
      }
      isProcessing = false; // End the processing
    });
  });

  archive.pipe(output);
  archive.directory(baseFolder, false);
  await archive.finalize();
};

// Use chokidar to monitor changes in the folder
chokidar.watch(baseFolder, { ignored: /[\/\\]\./ }).on('all', (event, path) => {
  if (event === 'add' || event === 'change' || event === 'unlink') {
    createZipArchive();
  }
});

console.log('Bot is running and watching for changes...');
```

My goal is to have a folder with many subfolders and files. I frequently make changes to this folder, and I want it to automatically compress into a zip file and send it to my Telegram channel using Node.js. Here's the code, but when I run it, I don't receive the compressed folder sent to Telegram.

Comment: I am using the following library: npm install node-telegram-bot-api chokidar archiver moment